# Why isn't this add_filter function working as expected?

Tags: filters

Confused on why this isn't working...can anyone point out my mistake?

Here is the filterable content:

```
'next_text' => apply_filters('atbdp_pagination_next_text', directorist_icon( 'fas fa-chevron-right', false ))
```

Here is what I have for my filter but I'm getting no change in the output on the page.

```
add_filter( 'atbdp_pagination_next_text', 'directorist_next_label');
function directorist_next_label(){
  return 'next';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply_filters( $tag, $value, $param, $otherparam )
```

This is how the `apply_filters` function work. By default, the value is printed if no function is hooked with the filter.

It's not clear what `directorist_icon( 'fas fa-chevron-right', false )` prints here. But if it is showing "next" string at the output, the filter is working right.

If you need to print, then `echo apply_filters` will help.

If this description doesn't fit your necessity, you can explain what you want to achieve, I hope I can help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. directorist_icon( 'fas fa-chevron-right' false) shows a font awesome icon (chevon right). I want the text to say next instead of that chevron icon. Right now I'm seeing the icon.